# Java - SocketException: Connection Reset when Client Send Request

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

In [Java Network Programming 4th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028420.do), Chapter 10 about Secure Socket, there is an example of build Secure Server. The code can be find [here](https://github.com/jkorab/jnp4-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oreilly/jnp4/SecureOrderTaker.java).

I'm trying to make more simple version of the code. Here is my code:

```
 try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance(algorithm);
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        //char[] password = System.console().readPassword("Password: "); // open the .class with command line
        char[] password = {'t', 'h', 'i', 's', 'i', 's', 't', 'i', 'a', 'n'};

        ks.load(new FileInputStream("src/jnp4e.keys"), password);            
        kmf.init(ks, password);
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null); // null = accept the default

        // wipe the password
        Arrays.fill(password, '0');

        SSLServerSocketFactory factory
                = context.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket server
                = (SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(PORT);

        // add anonymous (non-authenticated) cipher suites
        String[] supported = server.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        String[] anonCipherSuitesSupported = new String[supported.length];
        int numAnonCipherSuitesSupported = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < supported.length; i++) {
            if (supported[i].indexOf("_anon_") > 0) {
                anonCipherSuitesSupported[numAnonCipherSuitesSupported++]
                        = supported[i];
            }
        }
        String[] oldEnabled = server.getEnabledCipherSuites();
        String[] newEnabled = new String[oldEnabled.length
                + numAnonCipherSuitesSupported];
        System.arraycopy(oldEnabled, 0, newEnabled, 0, oldEnabled.length);
        System.arraycopy(anonCipherSuitesSupported, 0, newEnabled,
                oldEnabled.length, numAnonCipherSuitesSupported);
        server.setEnabledCipherSuites(newEnabled);

        System.out.println("OK..");

        // Now all the set up is complete and we can focus
        // on the actual communication.
        while (true) {
            // This socket will be secure,
            // but there's no indication of that in the code!
            try (Socket theConnection = server.accept()) {
                InputStream in = theConnection.getInputStream();
                Reader r = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
                int c;
                while ((c = r.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.write(c);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The only diffence is in my code I create a `Reader` so the server can read characters. 
I tried this server with simple client that send text. Here is the Client:

```
int port = 7000; // default https port
    String host = "localhost";
    SSLSocketFactory factory
            = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();


    SSLSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);

        // enable all the suites
        String[] supported = socket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(supported);

        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        out.write("Hello");

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

I run the Server first and then the Cient. But when the Server accept input from Client it throws this exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
...
```

UPDATE CLIENT
Based on dave answer, I add 2 lines of code `flush()` and `close()`

```
...
out.write("Hello");
out.flush();
socket.close();
...
```

But another exception arrive:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

Comment: Why are you enabling anonymous cipher suites when you already have a keystore? Which presumably contains a private key and certificate?

Comment: just make this server more flexible, i guess

Comment: It just makes your server insecure, you mean. Don't do this.

Comment: @EJP it can make the **client(s)** insecure; the server already isn't requesting or getting client-auth. Server tests like ssllabs will downgrade a server for *allowing* anonymous suite(s), but even so the client can prevent actual use of an anonymous suite and most do by default, including JSSE; the client code here overrides the default and allows anonymous, but doesn't prefer it, so most servers (also including JSSE here) still won't use it.

Comment: @EJP I actually find it disappointing that a [Java Networking book suggests using anonymous cipher suites without making it clear what the implications are](https://library.oreilly.com/book/0636920028420/java-network-programming-4th-edition/195.xhtml?ref=toc#javanp3-CHP-10-SECT-8.1) ("*Choosing the Cipher Suites*" section, although there is a brief sentence after Example 10-2 apparently).

Comment: @Bruno the book just show us all the types of cipher suites JSSE provide and how to enabled them but it actually suggests to not using anon "You should probably avoid any of these suites
that contain NULL, ANON, or EXPORT in their names unless you want the NSA to
read your messages."

Comment: @AltianoGerung True, but from experience (especially questions here on SO), many learners will try to use the shortest path possible to get their code working: this often involves trying to skip the steps required to deal with certificates (e.g. by using anon cipher suites or disabling trust verification altogether). I haven't read the full book, but these pages make no mention of host name verification either, which is another step that should be taken (much easier to do since Java 7, btw).

Comment: @Bruno then can you give some references (links, books, blogs ..) to do it in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OutputStreamWriter on a socket stream apparently buffers and your client **didn't `.flush()` or `.close()`** so your data isn't actually sent.

If your Java program (or more exactly JVM) **exits without doing `.close()`** on a socket stream (including closing a Writer which passes through to the Stream) handling depends on the platform; on Windows it sends a RST which causes the **"Connection reset"** exception you see at the peer. Unix closes the connection normally at the TCP level, which is actually not fully normal for SSL/TLS, but "close enough" (as it were) that Java treats it as EOF.

**Edit** for followon question:

Server getting SSLHandshakeException **"received alert <strike>bad_certificate</strike>certificate_unknown"** which *theoretically could mean a few things but almost always* means that the certificate the server is using (from the keystore you loaded, along with matching privatekey) is not signed by a CA (Certificate Authority) trusted by the client.

The code you show for the client doesn't do anything to set or alter its truststore; if there isn't code elsewhere that does so, or external settings like the `java` commandline option `-Dx=y` to set system properties, the client will use the JSSE **default truststore**, which is the file `JRE/lib/security/jssecacerts` if it exists otherwise the file `JRE/lib/security/cacerts` (where JRE is the directory where your JRE is installed; if you use a JDK, the JRE is a subdirectory of the JDK directory). If you (and anyone else on your system) haven't modified these files since the JRE was installed, `jssecacerts` doesn't exist and `cacerts` contains a set of **"well-known root" CAs** determined by Oracle, like Verisign and Equifax etc.

Thus, you need to either:

- use a certificate issued by a **well-known CA**; if you don't already have such a cert you have to obtain it from the CA by proving (at least) your control of the domain name(s) certified and depending on the CA possibly paying a fee; if you do have or get such a cert, install it in your keystore, *in* the privatekey entry, *with* any chain certs (for well-known CAs there almost always is at least one chain cert).
- use a certificate issued by any **other CA**, including an adhoc CA you make up, and **including** as the limit case a **selfsigned** certificate which is implicitly its own CA, such as the one `keytool -genkeypair` generates automatically; and put the CA certificate for that CA (or that selfsigned cert) **into the truststore used** by the client. For that there are two ways:

  - put the server's CA cert (or selfsigned cert) in the default truststore file of the JRE used by the client. This does affect any other programs sharing that default truststore, which is potentially all other programs using that JRE. If you use `jssecacerts` it only affects JSSE, if you use `cacerts` it also affects the verification of signed code (if any), plus it gets wiped out if you upgrade your JRE in place, as usually is automatic on Windows.
  - create (or reuse) another truststore, put the server's CA cert in there, and have the client use that nondefault truststore. There are several options for that: set the system properties for the default truststore externally, set them explicitly in your program (before first use of JSSE!), explicitly load a "keystore" file (actually containing the cert(s)) and use its trustmanager in a nondefault SSLSocketFactory much like your server code does for keymanager, or even write your own trustmanager with whatever store(s?) you like and use that similarly.

**Edit#2 Simple Example**

Covering all these options in detail would be much too long, but **one** simple option is as follows.

1. Generate keypair and (default) selfsigned certificate:

`keytool -genkeypair -keystore ksfile -keyalg RSA`

For the prompt "first and last name" (which is actually the CommonName attribute in the cert) enter the name of the server, in particular the name the client(s) will use to connect to the server; in the question this is "localhost". The other name fields don't matter; fill or omit them as you like, except that Country if used must be 2 letters as the prompt says. Instead of answering the prompts, you can add on the command line `-dname "CN=common_name_value"`. If you have more than one name for the server(s) there are some options omitted here.
For some other applications you may need to specify the entry name with `-alias name`; for this question it isn't needed.

2. Get a copy of the certificate:

`keytool -exportcert -rfc -keystore ksfile [-alias name] -file certfile`

In this example the client is on the same machine as the server. In another case it would be necessary to copy the contents of this file from the server to the client; this is often done most conveniently by copying the file.

3. Put cert in client truststore. As above there are many options, but the one you will probably see suggested the most often because it is usually the quickest to start is to just put it in the JRE default file, cacerts:

`keytool -importcert -keystore JRE/lib/security/cacerts -file certfile`

where JRE is the directory where your JRE (Java Runtime Environment) is installed. This depends on your OS and how you installed your JRE (or JDK, which includes a JRE) such as with a package manager or not. If you have more than one JRE and/or JDK installed, it depends which one you are using.

On Unix if you invoke `java` without specifying a path, `which java` (or in bash and perhaps other shells, `type java`) will tell you the full pathname that is run. Note however this is often a symbolic link to the real location, which should be in the form `/somewhere/java[version]/bin/java`; change the `bin/java` part to `lib/security/cacerts`.

On Windows, if you install a normal "system-wide" Java, the program you run is `%windir%\system32\java.exe` where `windir` is usually `c:\windows` but the actual code and files for JRE are in `c:\program files\java\jreN` or `c:\program files (x86)\java\jreN` depending on your architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) and jreN is currently `jre7` or `jre8` as applicable, but likely to expand in the future. Or run the Java Control Panel; in the Java tab the View button shows location(s) of the installed JRE(s).

Comment: `OutputStreamWriter` buffers, all by itself. It has nothing to do with 'on a socket'. Java does not treat  FIN as EOF under SSL: you will get an SSL alert, as an SSLException. Not that's it's relevant to this question.

Comment: @dave: i update my code as you can see above. But, new exception arrive `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown`. What that go wrong now?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 A quick question. is bad_certificate = certificate_unknown? the excption is : certificate_unknown

Comment: @AltianoGerung sorry, the edit window doesn't leave the question or comments visible and I misremembered; fixed, and improved a little too.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: ok. that is a very good answer, and i think for this particular question the answer can be accepted. But it would be better for me if you can add a tutorial for each of the options you gave or give me a link or any reference to do it? My number 1 priority is option 2 (other CA) and the first way of it (selfsigned cert).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 are you still there?

Comment: @AltianoGerung (I took some time off for the weekend) A complete tutorial would be much too long for me if not for SE; Ivan Ristic (the man behind the well-regarded www.ssllabs.com) just published a 528-page book on this https://www.feistyduck.com/books/bulletproof-ssl-and-tls/ . I edited in *one* simple case.

Comment: @EJP I did expect an Exception but in my tests it didn't occur. I tested the case easiest for me to create: client (on Unix) opens server and handshakes, client does one write on stream then exits, server does two reads on stream. On 7u80 and 8u45 the second read gets length -1 (EOF) and no Exception; Wireshark confirms only FIN/ACK without alert(shutdown). If you give details for a case that does raise the exception I'll be glad to try it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the link and ofc for the answer too. (i know you had to have a weekend so i wait for 2 days before commenting again :D)